# Ads disappear from the main page (UWP App)

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

I'm developing an uwp app, and I have an Ad on the main page. Also on the main page I have a button to remove this advertisement. I have it all done, and it works without any problem. However when I enter the app (on the main page) the advertisement is displayed and the button to remove it too, but if I navigate to another page (for example for the settings) and return to the main page the advertisement disappears without my having removed it.

Why this happen?
In my XAML of main page I have: `Visibility="Visible"` (for button and ad)

This is my code (it removes the ad and the button, when the button is clicked):

```
if (results.Status == ProductPurchaseStatus.Succeeded)
    {
      RemoveAds.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
      Ad.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button to remove ads (in app purchase) does not disappear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43052338/button-to-remove-ads-in-app-purchase-does-not-disappear)

Comment: The question is different. Here are the ads that disappear when navigating to another page without removing them. On the other issue is the remove button that does not disappear, already after I remove the ads. These are completely different issues!

Answer (score 0):

It's quite likely a bug in AdControl which has bitten others too. To make sure, disable main page's NavigationCache:

```
NavigationCacheMode="Disabled"
```

Now, when user navigates back to the main page, the page should be a "fresh" instance. Your ad should work.

To make the AdControl work between page navigations you can try recreating the AdControl everytime user navigates back to the page. There's maybe some useful info here: [AdControl stops updating after navigating back in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068329/adcontrol-stops-updating-after-navigating-back-in-uwp).

Other option is to add the AdControl into your Frame, not into your page. This way your ad is always there, on every page.

Comment: This: `NavigationCacheMode="Disabled"` resolve my problem, thank you! Ads dont disappear now. And thanks for the suggestion, but in this app I just want the ads to be on the main page